# Store eval output in variable

Tags: bash

I'm new to Bash and trying to store eval command output in a variable. This is my code to check Java version:

```
javaPath="/opt/Java/i386/jre1.8.0_181/bin/Java -version"
output=eval $javaPath
echo "Java version is: $output"
```

Output:

```
java version "1.8.0_181"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build ...)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server ...
Java version is:
```

Question: how can I store command output in `$output`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to use `eval` here. Don't use it unless you clearly know what you are trying to do with it. See [Eval command and security issues](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048)

For your use case, though a simple function would suffice. Also I see the `java -version` gets printed to standard error stream `stderr(2)` instead of `stdout(1)`.

```
javaVersion() {
    /opt/Java/i386/jre1.8.0_181/bin/Java -version 2>&1 >/dev/null
}
```

and put the result in a variable using command substitution, `$(..)` which runs your command puts the result in a variable

```
ouput="$(javaVersion)"
printf '%s\n' "$output"
```